# how to looping one data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have page for barcode print by id product

like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LekwH.jpg

i want page show 20 barcode like picture bellow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgAle.jpg

I only have 1 barcode data but I want to display as many as 20 barcodes on the page ...
so, when I print a barcode, I can print as many as 20 barcodes, not just one

my controller :

```
public function barcodes($id){
    $title = $this->title; 

    $products = Product::find($id);
    $vars = compact('products');

    $data = ['products' => $products];
    return view($title.'.barcodes',compact('data','products'));
}
```

blade view:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card-box">
         <div class="header-title"> 
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" >
            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
            Print
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body" id="printableArea">
            <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #adadad;display:inline-block;line-height:16px !important; " align="center">
               <p>{{$products->name}}</p>
               <?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($products->code, "c128A",1,40,array(1,1,1), true) . '"   />'; ?>
               <br>
               <small style="font-size: 8px !important;"><b>{{$products->code}}</b></small>
               <p style="line-height: 12px !important; font-size: 8px !important;">
                  <b>Price: {{$products->sale_price}} </b>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   function printDiv(divName) {
       var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
       var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
       document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
       window.print();
       document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any loop anywhere in your blade file? Do you have 20 barcode data in database?

Comment: no, I only have 1 barcode data but I want to display as many as 20 barcodes on the page ...
so, when I print a barcode, I can print as many as 20 barcodes, not just one

Comment: You must have atleast 20 barcode so that you can print 20? Loop is essential for repeated task. Please share screenshot of your database table with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only have 1 barcode data but I want to display as many as 20
>   barcodes on the page ... so, when I print a barcode, I can print as
>   many as 20 barcodes, not just one

Use [@for](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#loops)

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
    // put HTML for barcode here
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

This will loop over each of the $products

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)
              <div class="card-box">
             <div class="header-title"> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" >
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                Print
                </a>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body" id="printableArea">
                <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #adadad;display:inline-block;line-height:16px !important; " align="center">
                   <p>{{$products->name}}</p>
                   <?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($products->code, "c128A",1,40,array(1,1,1), true) . '"   />'; ?>
                   <br>
                   <small style="font-size: 8px !important;"><b>{{$products->code}}</b></small>
                   <p style="line-height: 12px !important; font-size: 8px !important;">
                      <b>Price: {{$products->sale_price}} </b>
                   </p>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    @endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops

Answer (score 1):

One way you can use is **foreach loop**.

In your case you can do something like this.

```
@foreach($products AS $product)
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card-box">
             <div class="header-title"> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" >
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                Print
                </a>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body" id="printableArea">
                <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #adadad;display:inline-block;line-height:16px !important; " align="center">
                   <p>{{$product->name}}</p>
                   <?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($product->code, "c128A",1,40,array(1,1,1), true) . '"   />'; ?>
                   <br>
                   <small style="font-size: 8px !important;"><b>{{$product->code}}</b></small>
                   <p style="line-height: 12px !important; font-size: 8px !important;">
                      <b>Price: {{$product->sale_price}} </b>
                   </p>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

---

[Foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.